# How can I enable BinaryLiterals?

Tags: haskell, ghc

There's a BinaryLiterals extension mentioned in the Language.Haskell.Extensions document. The idea is you can say `0b11 == 3`.

```
> :set -XBinaryLiterals
Some flags have not been recognized: -XBinaryLiterals
```

Comment: I'm using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-literal-qq as a "poor man's BInaryLiterals", for good effect, in `mos6502-kansas-lava`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9224, it is slated for release in version 7.10.1.  This doesn't seem to be released yet.

Comment: GHC 7.10.1 has *definitely* not been released yet. It's not even (quite) reached a feature freeze, although that's expected to happen within a few weeks. You can get a sneak peek by cloning the git repository and compiling it yourself (it will call itself 7.9.something). The compiler and included libraries mostly work right, but expect to fight with any external packages—you'll likely need pre-release versions of those, including cabal and a couple of criterion dependencies.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting. I wonder how I could get in on that process. I'd love to see it work like verilog so you can say `3b111` acts like it's in a 3-bit register so `3b111 + 1 = 3b000`.

Comment: @MichaelFox They are standard `Int`s as far as I know so no.

Comment: @alternative It's too bad. Haskell seems to have a long history of being almost a good way to model digital designs but still misses many features. I can define the functionality with an ordinary data type but would like to get involved with sugaring the syntax. Maybe TemplateHaskell can help. I don't know it yet.

Comment: @MichaelFox, all you need to know about the process can be found on the [GHC developer wiki](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc). Changes can be proposed through the bug tracking system there and/or on the ghc-devs mailing list. Grand new ideas are very unlikely to make it into 7.10 at this point, but of course bug fixes and small improvements likely will, and 7.12 is wide open.

Comment: @MichaelFox You could just have a `Register (nbits :: Nat)` type and construct that with this syntax.

Comment: @MichaelFox Its not a hardware description language. Such features should never be implemented in the language itself.

Comment: @alternative I just want high-level behavioral modeling of digital systems but [lots](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xilinx-lava) of [people](http://clash.ewi.utwente.nl) like Haskell as an [HDL](http://www.bluespec.com). And Verilog is godawful. So what if we want 3b111? You were never going to type that. Why rain on our parade?